# Blogspot add image in side panel with link

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I have a blog in blogspot and I would like to add in my right panel an image with a link. When the visitor clicks on it it will open that link.

For example, let say I add the logo of "NYTimes" and the user clicks on it and the nytimes page opens.

Edit: I tried the Gadget Add JavaScript/Html code and I put this

```
   <a href="www.nytimes.com" >
   <img src="logo.png" height="15" width="80" />
   </a>
```

but it try to link to myblogXXX.blogspot.com/www.nytimes.com
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is absolutely correct. Just change add http to your address and blogger will stop trying to look within your blog:

```
<a href="http://www.nytimes.com" >
<img src="logo.png" height="15" width="80" />
</a>
```

That works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes all is correct but I usually use **target** and **alt** attributes with link.

`alt="_LITTLE_DESCRIPTION_"` Shows up when something wrong and picture don't load in page.

`target="_blank"` Always open links in new tab. So you can keep visitors in your page longer.

```
<a href="_YOUR_LINK_"><img style="border:0;" src="_YOUR_PICTURE_LINK_" alt="_LITTLE_DESCRIPTION_" target="_blank" height="15" width="80"/></a>
```